# How to disable (or remove) the "protect sheet" and "protect workbook" button in excel 2007 menu?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm using VBA and I would like to disable the "protect sheet" and "protect workbook" button in excel 2007 menu.

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance for any help.
Best regards

Comment: Check out this article as well: http://excelusergroup.org/blogs/nickhodge/archive/2008/02/03/ribbon-step-by-step-part-3-the-office-menu-and-re-purposing.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot affect the ribbon using VBA without the "customUI xml mechanism". See [Excel 2007: Ribbon customization - Disable custom buttons](http://sheetal-d.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!237C3DEA7120098B!609.entry?sa=490475961).

To learn more about RibbonX, you can read this MSDN article: [Using RibbonX from Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163410.aspx).

Comment: The first link has to do with disabling **custom** buttons. The protect sheet button is built-in.

Comment: The first link is **dead** :(