# Disable Insert Sheet/ Delete Sheet Menu using VBA in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to Disable the Sheet Delete and Sheet Insert Menu by using VBA in Excel 2007 using the RibbonID Number?

This works well with Excel 2003. But i have no idea of the code in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 0):

See point 3 for a example file to do it with VBA on this page
http://www.rondebruin.nl/ribbon.htm

[EDIT] Same subject discussed here : [How to disable (or remove) the "protect sheet" and "protect workbook" button in excel 2007 menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689019/how-to-disable-or-remove-the-protect-sheet-and-protect-workbook-button-in-e)